# Get the text before a MAC address from a line

Tags: bash

I want to get only the text before a MAC address from a line in a file named `idsxx.txt`.

File content:

```
ComPuteer AA A AA:Bb:CC:DD:EE:FF    Some \ /\7\ Info
ComPuteRb CC:DD:EE:FF:Aa:CC     Some Info  \ &&\7\ About
CompuY Third CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC               Some Infoz  &(/\)
```

How I want it:

```
ComPuteer AA A
ComPuteRb
CompuY Third
```

I want a solution that works on line like this:

```
cat idsxx.txt  | while read line 
do
    #working on $line
done
```

it can be fine like variable substitution

Comment: Why is the single `A` missing in the first line of your output? It's before MAC address.

Comment: The "single" A missing before MAC address, like you say, it's It's part of the name of the first computer in the example. Sometimes asking why it's usless! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cat idsxx.txt  | while read line 
do
    shortline=${line%% ??:??:??:??:??:*}
    #working on $shortline
done
```

This solution includes also the lonely `A` of the first input line into the variable you are working on.

Comment: Tested your solution on shortline and works. It reads line and export what i need xfectly. Great! You'r the king bash master. You haven't use any command. I don't know how you do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the matching pattern and everything after it.

```
sed -r 's/([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}.*//' idsxx.txt
```

You can process the output with

```
while read -r line; do
   echo "line=${line}"
done < <(sed -r 's/([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}.*//' idsxx.txt)
```

Comment: for your solution "Delete the matching pattern and everything after it" whit sed, but what Pierre François posted wors on line and it's what i want. Thaks the same

Comment: When you don't want to echo the full line in the loop you can process it like my edit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but when i was doing that i thinked that Pierre François solution is more restricted and don't uses external command for the loop but only bash variables replacing. So beautiful edit for the answer, but the propose for the process in full loop is already solved by Pierre François and works very good. :)

Comment: Please accept the answer of Pierre, when that is what you want. FYI When you add a lot of processing in the while-loop, than you will be creating a lot of subprocesses and get a bad performance.

Comment: "FYI When you add a lot of processing in the while-loop, than you will be creating a lot of subprocesses and get a bad performance" -> are not more then 30-40 computers. "Please accept the answer of Pierre, when that is what you want." -> can't accept it becouse i'm too little.

Comment: "I thought there was no minimal score before you can act like stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)" Thanks 4 u link. 
I didn't think it could be done without a minimum score <3